# PcapDotNet System.IO.FileNotFoundException in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pcapdotnet

I have a C# solution (.Net 7.0) where I recently added the PcapDotNet libraries.
Now I run the project and I keep getting this error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PcapDotNet.Core, Version=0.10.0.20632, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b6f3e583145a652'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

I tried downgrading the target framework but still doesn't work.I know it's weird to say this, but it already worked "before".
The project has no errors and I obviously need this library to work with network packages.

Any hints to solving this?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The issue arrises when I use the line `if (communicator.ReceivePacket(out Packet packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok)` where I am warned with `The type 'Packet' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must a reference to assembly 'PcapDotNet.Packets, Version=0.10.0.20603, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'`

The mentioned `Packet` class comes from `using PcapDotNet.Core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by downgrading the library to `PcapDotNet (0.10.1)`, clicking on the project name on Visual Studio, and then deleting the code there and pasting instead this one:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PcapDotNet" Version="0.10.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your project was built in `Release` mode and not `Debug`. Do not forget to check if this dependency really exists, with your particular `PublicKeyToken` and `Version`.

Also, please see the [Using Pcap.Net in your programs](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Using-Pcap.Net-in-your-programs) guide and the [FAQ](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/FAQ) (question #6).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried the release built but still threw the same exception.
How can I check the PublicKeyToken part? I've never gave it in before

Comment: You can follow this [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/how-to--determine-the-public-key-token-of-the-windows-client-control-add-in-and-.net-framework-assembly). It should be something like this command in CMD: `sn -T C:\Path\To\Your.dll`.

Comment: i did so but: (a) when path enclosed with quotation marks it did not "do" anything but showing the help menu, and when without, it said ´xxx.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly´

Comment: Can you find something like 
    `<PackageReference Include="PcapDotNet.Core" Version="0.10.0.20632" PublicKeyToken="4b6f3e583145a652">` in your `.csproj` file? Try remove `PublicKeyToken` and rebuild the project.

Comment: no, just have "<PackageReference Include="PcapDotNet" Version="0.10.2" />" in project.wpf file

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package ***x86***?

Comment: Additionally, please make sure that there are references to `PcapDotNet.Base.dll`, `PcapDotNet.Packets.dll`, `PcapDotNet.Core.dll`, and `PcapDotNet.Core.Extensions.dll` in every project that uses PcapDotNet.

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot boundaring what causes the issue... thanks for the support